# Formula for excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Help me please, to find a formula for excel, which takes all the words in the text (for example, text from column A) and gives all the words from the text without repeating in a column B.

For example,

Column A
Text

Although simplicity is a virtue, theories regarding pedagogy do not work in practice if they are black and white. To say that the best way to teach is only to praise positive actions and to ignore negative ones is like saying that strawberries reduce one’s risk for cancer so people should cut apples out of their diet and only eat strawberries. In both situations, there does not have to be a choice.

Column B - Words from text

Although
 simplicity
is
 a
 virtue,
 theories
regarding
 pedagogy
 do
 not
work
in
practice
if
they
are
black
and
white.
To
say
that
the
best
way
to
teach
is
only
to
praise
positive
actions
and
to
ignore
negative
ones
is
like
saying
that
strawberries
reduce
one’s
risk
for
cancer
so
people
should
cut
apples
out
of
their
diet
and
only
eat
strawberries.
In
both
situations,
there
does
not
have
to
be
a
choice.

Comment: Where did `is` and `a` go? Or the comma? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I need all words from text in column A to give in column B like this:

Comment: Single words in column **A** or phrases and sentences??

Comment: In column A I have whole text, and in column B I need only words from this text. Words need to be constructed in column. I need this to compare words from column B with words from another text in column for example C.

Comment: @user4166, in your original question you have: _and gives all the words from the text __without repeating__ in a column B._, but in your example in column B you have repeating words (e.g., "to", "only, "that" and so on). So, should all words be unique in result column B or repeatings are allowed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather complex thing for a single formula .... here's a method ...

**part 1**: splitting a text into single words:

- A1: your text
- A3: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")` .... removing commas
- A5= `=SUBSTITUTE(A3,".","")` .... removing full stops (repeat this for other punctations you might have
- A8: constant value `0`
- A9: `=FIND(" ",$A$5,A8+1)` .... find the first blank in $A$5 after the position indicated by the cell above .... copy this formula down until you get the first `#VALUE` error
- B9: `=MID($A$5,A8+1,A9-A8-1)` .... extract the word between previous and this blank position .... copy this formula down until you get the first `#VALUE` error

when you are happy with your split list, copy/paste as values the list and do some headers

[image]

**part 2**: finding uniques words:

You need to find each unique word exactly once. A method strictly without VBA would consist of the following:

- sort the text in column B ascending
- enter in C8: `=IF(B8=B7,C7+1,1)` and copy down to end of list ... you create a "running number starting with 1 and continuing to increment as long as the word remains the same
- autofilter column C for value = 1 ... this will display the first occurence of each word
- copy / paste the filtered list to whereever you want to store it for further processing ... I recommend a sheet different from your raw data

[image]

You can restore the original sort order of the result by sorting on the numeric values in column A.

As you can see in the example of words "in", "to", this method is case insensitive. A limitation is a possible false seperation between "ones" and "one's" ... this needs to be decided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need help with another question: what excel formula can help to make comparison of words from column A and words from column B, then find unique words from both columns and extract them in column C.

Comment: Example:
Although praise Although
simplicity positive simplicity
is actions is
a and a
virtue, to virtue,
theories ignore theories
regarding negative regarding
pedagogy ones pedagogy
cancer is cancer
so like so
people saying people
should that should
cut strawberries cut
  praise
  positive
  actions
  and
  to
  ignore
  negative
  ones
  like
  saying
  that
  strawberries

Comment: If you have columns of single words in A and B, `VLOOKUP()` will help you check if the word argument from A is present anywhere in range B (and vice versa). Having done this intersection you can extract the resulting set and apply the same what I wrote under "finding unique words"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1;" ";REPT(" ";LEN($A$1)));1+(ROW(A1)-1)*LEN($A$1);LEN($A$1)))
```

Assuming test in A1, write formula in B1 and copy down till you got last word

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","